# Getting "?" for ASCII values

Tags: java, char, int

I wanted to see what all the character values were in ASCII so I wrote this really quick loop that did the following.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000; i++){
   System.out.println("(int, char) " + "( "+ i + " , " +(char) i + "     )");
}
```

and the results I get do not seem correct. They are fine up to 128. Then all i get is question marks, here are some of the results...

```
(int, char) ( 121 , y )
(int, char) ( 122 , z )
(int, char) ( 123 , { )
(int, char) ( 124 , | )
(int, char) ( 125 , } )
(int, char) ( 126 , ~ )
(int, char) ( 127 ,  )
(int, char) ( 128 , ? )
(int, char) ( 129 , ? )
(int, char) ( 130 , ? )
(int, char) ( 131 , ? )
(int, char) ( 132 , ? )
(int, char) ( 133 , ? )
(int, char) ( 134 , ? )
(int, char) ( 135 , ? )
(int, char) ( 136 , ? )
(int, char) ( 137 , ? )
(int, char) ( 138 , ? )
(int, char) ( 139 , ? )
(int, char) ( 140 , ? )
(int, char) ( 141 , ? )
(int, char) ( 142 , ? )
(int, char) ( 143 , ? )
(int, char) ( 144 , ? )
(int, char) ( 145 , ? )
(int, char) ( 146 , ? )
(int, char) ( 147 , ? )
(int, char) ( 148 , ? )
(int, char) ( 149 , ? )
(int, char) ( 150 , ? )
(int, char) ( 151 , ? )
(int, char) ( 152 , ? )
(int, char) ( 153 , ? )
(int, char) ( 154 , ? )
(int, char) ( 155 , ? )
(int, char) ( 156 , ? )
(int, char) ( 157 , ? )
(int, char) ( 158 , ? )
(int, char) ( 159 , ? )
```

Why are they appearing as question marks all the way up to 1000. They should be a bunch of digits I will never need besides basic encryption. Any ideas why this is so?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever you are using to display the output is not capable of displaying those characters.

In general all display devices cope with characters up to 127 (but note that some of those are actually linefeeds, etc so not displayable as glyphs) but characters beyond that depends on the capabilities of the display.

A common "fallback" is to replace any characters that it can't handle with a ? character. You also sometimes see a black square used for that purpose too.

Comment: To expand: it's replacing non-[ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters with a `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Chars in java are not ASCII encoded, but UTF16, therefore you get the corresponding UTF16 characters. There are several control codepoints starting from index 128, that's why you get questionmarks as substitution. BTW: ASCII contains only characters up to index 127.